# Is there a way to open a text file into python code (similar to doing CTRL+O on windows)?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was a way to open a file that a user would download to some directory. Since I don't know what  directory that could be, I want my code to do the equivalent of the CTRL+O command in order for the user to select the correct file after starting my script. Not sure if there is a way to do this though.

Comment: What do you mean by "import"? You should probably be using the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function.

Comment: I reworded the q

Comment: I believe the question is about creating the "Open..." dialog and file picker, rather than just how to open a file.